# Swift 3 JsonSerialization

Tags: swift3

**Code**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
@IBAction func btnGirisYap(_ sender: Any) {
    let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.kerimcaglar.com/yemek-tarifi")!

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url as URL) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        if let urlContent = data {

            do {

                let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! [String:AnyObject]

                //print (jsonResult)
                self.txtGirisKullaniciAdi.text  = jsonResult["malzemeler"] as! NSString as String    
            } catch {

                print("JSON serialization failed")
            }

        } else {

            print("ERROR FOUND HERE")
        }

    }

    task.resume()
    }
}
```

Can you help with this?

[image: Error Screen Shoot]

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you clearly that the deserialized object is an array rather than a dictionary.

```
let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: urlContent, options: []) as! [[String:Any]]
for item in jsonResult {
  print(item["malzemeler"] as! String) // cast directly to String
}
```

Notes:

- The unspecified JSON dictionary type in Swift 3 is `[String:Any]`.
- The `mutableContainers` option is useless in Swift.